# Twitter mining using streaming API, python

Tags: python, api, twitter, data-mining, keyword-search

I want to crawl Tweet data with keywords: 'trump', 'clinton'. I usually use Jupyter Notebook to use Python3. Following is my code, it stops when I run cells.

I inserted some other codes between the codes to get the error but doesn't work either..

```
def limit_handled(cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield cursor.next()
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            time.sleep(15 * 60)
```

Followings are the codes.

```
import tweepy

# OAuth setup
consumer_key = '000000000'
consumer_secret = '000000000'
access_token = '0000000000'
access_secret = '000000000'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)  

class MyListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('tweet_stream.json', 'a') as file:
                file.write(data)
                print(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: {}".format(str(e)))
        return True


twitter_stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['trump', 'clinton'])
```

Codes using Jupyter Notebook:

Comment: Ooops, your *secret* codes are on the screenshot. You need to regenerate your auth keys, so you don't become a spam bot.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited the screenshot and regenerated my keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `api` object into the stream object. Try changing the line:

`twitter_stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, MyListener())`

to

`twitter_stream = tweepy.Stream(api, MyListener())`